# Function composition as representable by matrices?

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, function-and-relation-composition

I know from linear algebra that for different sets of functions differentiation can be expressed using matrix multiplication on a vector representation of the function. For instance polynomials and exponential functions. For example:
$$D = \left[\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right] , \text{if} \sin = \left[\begin{array}{r}1\\0\end{array}\right] \text{and} \cos = \left[\begin{array}{r}0\\1\end{array}\right]$$
Another famous set of functions which have nice and simple such matrices are the polynomials.

Now to my question: are there sets of functions for which we can create same kind of matrices for function composition?

For instance if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ polynomials, to find or systematically build a matrix such that $D_p q$ represents $p(q)$ as a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Carleman matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix), defined as
$$
M[f]_{jk} = \frac{1}{k!}\left[\frac{d^k}{dx^k} (f(x))^j\right]_{x = 0},
$$
convert function composition to matrix multiplication. The functions are required to be analytic at $0$ (for the usual definition) or at some $x_0$ (if derivatives are taken at $x_0$ instead of $0$ in the above definition).
They satisfy $M[f \circ g] = M[f] M[g]$.
Similar concepts are [Bell matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix#Bell_matrix) and [Jabotinsky matrices](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2032522?seq=1).

Comment: There seems to be a connection to Taylor expansions. Would this mean it is easy to extend to multivariable functions? Anyway, now I have something to experiment with. Thank you :)